# Creating Pages for Django Admin add_form Inline Children

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a node_user which extends auth.User in my django application. The node_user has many children. When creating a new node_user in the django admin I also provide access to node_users's child objects using the StackedInline sublclass.

However, I want to present the node_user children in a series of pages instead of a stacked one-page list. Is there anyway to spread the children out over pages? Does someone have an example? I think this would help user interaction but I'm unsure how to do it because I'm a newbie.

Thanks
angelo

Answer (score 0):

Django doesn't do this out of the box sorry. You could write a custom admin view but you'd have some tricky decisions to make and coding to do regarding saving. I.e. does hitting 'next' lose changes you made on the first page? My approach to this problem would be to edit the node_user children through their own ModelAdmin - smart use of the list_filter and/or search_fields options (and perhaps list_editable) should make it pretty easy to edit them as a group.